# Custom Future objects

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I'd like to create custom Future objects.

The following code works fine

```
ThreadPoolExecutor mExecutor;
Future<?> f = mExecutor.submit(new DownloadRunnable(task, itemId));
```

I'd like to take the return value of submit and assign it to MyFuture object, with additional calls.
I've made the following changes, and getting a cast exception... Any suggestions?

```
ThreadPoolExecutor mExecutor;
// cast exception
MyFuture<?> f = (MyFuture<?>) mExecutor.submit(new DownloadRunnable(task, itemId));
f.setVer(true);


public class MyFuture<?> implements Future<?> {
    Boolean myVar;

    public void setVar(Boolean v) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want custom `Future`?

Comment: The executor returns its own type of Future. Why do you think you'll be able to cast it to your own class?

Comment: The problem comes from submit which only returns a `future<?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a constructor by passing `Future<?>`

```
 public class MyFuture<?> extends Future<?> 
{
      Boolean myVar;
      Future<?> fut;
      MyFuture<?>(Future<?> fut)
      {
           this.fut = fut;
      }

      public void setVar(Boolean v) 
      {
          ...
      }
}
```

So the following line

```
  MyFuture<?> f = (MyFuture<?>) mExecutor.submit(new DownloadRunnable(task, itemId));
```

becomes

```
  MyFuture<?> f = new MyFuture<?>(mExecutor.submit(new DownloadRunnable(task, itemId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `Future` is an interface and you should have written it like:

```
public class MuFuture<T> implements Future<T> {

}
```

And then I hope the code will work:

```
MyFuture<?> f = (MyFuture<?>) mExecutor.submit(new DownloadRunnable(task, itemId));
f.setVer(true);
```

Comment: I wrote extends by mistake, its implements. I dont want to implement the Future interface I want to what was implemented by ThreadPoolExecutor and extend it.